# sml-mode in Emacs for Mac

Tags: macos, emacs, sml

I just created a .sml file but as I started to write, I realized that Emacs for Mac OS X didn't recognize the language. I would love to have colored text and auto-indentation if possible! I looked at other pages that seemed to have answers but I didn't really understand the instructions and wasn't sure if they were for the Mac version of Emacs. It would be very much appreciated if someone could explain to me in-depth how to get my Emacs to recognize smlnj. Thank you!

Comment: How about installing the `sml-mode` library if you haven't already done that?:  http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/sml-mode.html -- i.e., download it and put it in your `load-path`; put `(require 'sml-mode)` in your `.emacs` file; and configure the `auto-mode-alist` to associate sml extensions with `sml-mode` -- like this:  `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.sml\\'" . sml-mode))`.  Restart Emacs.  **DISCLOSURE**:  I have never tried any of this.

Comment: Have you looked at existing documentation for how to install SML support in Emacs?  What did you try, what happened?

Answer (score 0):

1. `M-x package-install` :return: `sml-mode` will install sml-mode from the "melpa" package repository if Emacs knows to look there.
2. If Emacs does not know to look at melpa, open your `.emacs` file. In Linux, this is `C-x C-f ~/.emacs`

and add:

```
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))
```